# There is a problem when starting the UA-ModelCompiler

Tags: opc

When I start the example there is a problem :

```
Could not load resource 'Opc.Ua.ModelCompiler.Design.BuiltInTypes.xml'.

Value Cannot be :null
```

And cannot generate the code.

Comment: your code provide the question

Comment: [This](https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-ModelCompiler/issues/46) should be related to your issue.